# Center aligning an unordered list with bullets in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center align an unordered list in Bootstrap - bullets included

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
  padding-left: 1em !important;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="text-center">
  <li class="text-center">This</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>my</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, with both `class= "text-center"`, the text of the list is centered aligned, but the bullets are stuck in the left portion of the screen.

How do I make the bullets centered aligned as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code into this

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li>This</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>my</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Display table will care about the box size based on inside value and margin auto will centralized the section.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `list-style-position` property:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
  padding-left: 1em !important;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
li {
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="text-center">
  <li>This</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>my</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **flex** to achieve this:

```css
.custom-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
  padding-left: 1em !important;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="custom-center">
<ul class="text-center">
  <li class="text-center">This</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>my</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, essentially the issue is the bullets are part of the ul element and therefore rendered at the beginning of each new line and aren't associated with the li. Because of this even if you get the list centered the bullets will be aligned together and not relative to the length of your list item.

I've copied your code from above. And as you can see, by adding a wrapper element with `flex` and to set the margin left/right `mx-auto` on the ul element. However this gets the issue described above where the dots are all aligned but centered, but relative to the longest line.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
  padding-left: 1em !important;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex">
    <ul class="text-center mx-auto">
      <li class="text-center">This</li>
      <li>is</li>
      <li>my</li>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>a bit longer item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Another solution would be to use pseudo elements on the list items themselves to create the dots and to set the `list-style: none` to remove the bullets generated by the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code that might solve the problem for you:

```
<div class="text-center">
   <ul>
     <li>This</li>
     <li>is</li>
     <li>my</li>
     <li>list</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```